# Setting the ContentType header when sending MultipartFormDataContent using HttpClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using HttpClient to upload a file to a WebAPI resource using the code below. Since I am using MultipartFormDataContent, the request message content type is set to multipart/form-data. In WebAPI, I am checking the content header to only allow text/plain media type. So, where do I set the content header for the file type if I am using HttpClient with MultipartFormDataContent.

```
try
{
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

    string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + "demo.txt");

    var filestream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    content.Add(new StreamContent(filestream), "file", fileName);

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            Content = content,
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost:64289/api/uploads/"), 
        };

    var client = new HttpClient();

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
                    /// 
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
                throw;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You can set ContentType property by using Headers property of StreamContent object, for example, in my case I am uploading an image and use following code:

```
        StreamContent image = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        image.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(imagePath));
```

Comment: I was confused by the MimeMapping class, where does that come from? The MediaTypeHeaderValue takes a string as an argument

Comment: @reggaeguitar yes you are correct, it takes a string. You can 'hardcode' a fixed content type if it doesn't change.

You often need to set the mime type based on the file name. This is what MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping function does.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping?view=netframework-4.8

This function isn't available in dot net core, see here for an alternative

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131326/using-mimemapping-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 2):

You can set ContentType use following code :

```
            var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
           
            var bytes = await video.GetBytes();
           
            var streamContent = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));
            streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", video.ContentType);
            streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", $"form-data; name=\"{video.FileName}\"; filename=\"{video.FileName}\"");
            
            formData.Add(streamContent, "file", $"{video.FileName}");
            
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"api/client/uploadVideo?deviceOs={deviceOs}")
            {
                Content = formData,
            };

            request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");
            
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```