# Return image from API - not using Core

Tags: c#, image, api, return-type

I have been trying to figure out how to return an image from an API.  I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39177684/4843530) which comes closest, but I think it uses Core, which I am not using.  The best I come up with is

```
    // GET: api/Documents/GetImage/ZJvNmUw991B-KOFj4rAf6ApkYOYuxfgZptZcQlk_k7nK0ZNFr7FGpfLdZZOYcLmXBAuYHWImnV8gCIezYfb9Rw2
    [ActionName("GetImage")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Byte[]))]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetImage(string parameter)
    {
        Bitmap icon = new Bitmap(500, 100);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(icon);
        RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(70, 90, 90, 50);
        g.DrawString("Hello World!", new Font("Tahoma", 8), Brushes.Black, rectf);
        g.Flush();

        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            icon.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            return Ok(memStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

Which does return the data, but as a byte array.  How do I tell the Ok Action result to send that back with a content type of "image/bmp"?

In an api test tool, I can send the request to `http://localhost:58173/api/Documents/GetImage/2` and I get a response of [200 OK] with a response content of "Qk12DQMAAAAAADYAAAAoAAAA9AEAAGQAAAA..." which clearly seems just the byte array representation of the bitmap.  When I use it in an html like this

```
    <img src="http://localhost:58173/api/Documents/GetImage/2" />
```

It is not able to display the image.  I assume it does not recognize that stream of bytes as an image... because it never got back a content type?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi

Comment: @RalfBönning - I had looked at that, but I kept getting squat.  Just figured out that the reason I was not getting the image is because I was not resetting the memory stream to position zero before using it for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a [`FileStreamResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filestreamresult(v=vs.118).aspx), for example:

```
return new FileStreamResult(memStream, "image/bmp");
```

Comment: It seems to have the same problem where the returned result is just seen as a file stream.  The content type does not seem to be going back.  My API test tool gives me [200 OK] and response body of `{"FileStream": {"_buffer": Qk12DQMAAA...`

Comment: Are you wrapping this in an `Ok(...)` by any chance?

Comment: No.  I just changed the signature of the method to use FileStreamResult as the type, and changed the return statement to exactly what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So, I went back to returning an HttpResponseMessage, but with a couple of very significant changes - gotchas that were killing me when I tried it before...

By doing `using (MemoryStream memStream = new Mem...` on the memory stream, I was causing it to get disposed of before the response was actually sent back, so the response was trying to build a message out of a no-longer existing memory stream.

Also, I was not rewinding the memory stream to position zero so the response message would get the whole thing.

Here is the resulting code that worked...

```
    [ActionName("GetImage")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(string parameter)
    {
        using (Bitmap icon = new Bitmap(500, 100))
        {

            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(icon);
            RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(10,10,480,80);
            g.DrawString("Hello World!", new Font("Tahoma", 20), Brushes.White, rectf);
            g.Flush();

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = Request.CreateResponse();
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            icon.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memStream.Position = 0;
            responseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
            responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp");
            return responseMessage;
        }
    }
```

The only thing is that this leaves me with the worry that I am leaving a memory stream out there, not disposed of.  Or does HttpResponseMessage class dispose of it after using it?  I think I read somewhere, while hunting for this answer, that it does do that.

Comment: Well, one think you _could_ clean up with `using` is the `Bitmap` object.