# Image doesn't render from System.Drawing.Image in C#

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to getting image from BlobUrl, but it cant render in the browser.

My code controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public System.Drawing.Image GetImage()
{

    var profileImage = Db.Candidate.Include(x => x.ProfileImage).AsNoTracking().Single().ProfileImage;
    var urlWithSharedAccessToken = _fileService.GetBlobUrl(profileImage.FileGuid, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    byte[] bytes = wc.DownloadData(urlWithSharedAccessToken);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

    return img;
}
```

Below is the browser response:

[image]

Can anybody tell me, what should I do to render the actual image from **System.Drawing.Image**

Comment: Return the bytes in the response  :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177576/how-to-to-return-an-image-with-web-api-get-method

Answer (score 1):

I have done by returning `ByteArrayContent` using `HttpResponseMessage`. My full code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("profile_image")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProfileImageData()
{
    var profileImage = Db.Candidate.Include(x => x.ProfileImage).AsNoTracking().Single().ProfileImage;

    using (var file = await _fileService.DownloadFileAsync(profileImage.FileGuid))
    {
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        await file.CopyToAsync(memory);

        // Create response message
        var message = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(memory.ToArray())
        };

        //Otroligt att man ska behöva kladda med detta, men "filename" i Content Disposition accepterar enbart us-ascii strängar i vissa webbläsare
        var encoder = Encoding.GetEncoding("us-ascii", new EncoderReplacementFallback(string.Empty), new DecoderExceptionFallback());
        string asciiFileName = encoder.GetString(encoder.GetBytes(profileImage.FileName));

        // Set content headers
        message.Content.Headers.ContentLength = memory.Length;
        message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(profileImage.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");
        message.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = asciiFileName,
            Size = file.Length
        };

        return new ResponseMessageResult(message);
    }
}
```