# how to fetch image in server in c# for web Api?

Tags: c#, webapi

i am creating web Api for retrieve  image from server folder,in c# , i need code for that, thanks in advance,

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Fileretrive")]
public void retrive(string filename)
{
    //var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos");
    var tempath = Path.Combine(root,filename);
    Directory.GetFiles(tempath);
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempath);

}
```

Comment: what is the error your facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to return an image with Web API Get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177576/how-to-to-return-an-image-with-web-api-get-method)

Comment: Btw, POST is used to send data to a server and GET is for requesting data from a specified resource. 2/. Your method return void.

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj i cant return File

Answer (score 0):

you are nearly there. first you need to return the action result. since you are streaming byte, use file as your return.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Fileretrive")]
public IActionResult retrive(string filename)
{
    //var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Photos");
    var tempath = Path.Combine(root,filename);
    Directory.GetFiles(tempath);
    byte[] byteArray = null;
    byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempath);
    // check your mime type, and set your unique file name. maybe use DateTime for your file name
    return File(byteArray , "image/jpeg", $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMMyyyy")}.jpeg"); 

}
```

Comment: while return File, i got an error 'System.IO.File' is a type but used like a variable

Comment: typo it should be byteArray instead of buffer

Comment: IActionResult  i got an error,the type or namespace name IActionResult  could not be found

Comment: @SanThoShKumar, use the light bulb on the type to get the using. should be `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`.

Comment: i am creating web Api not mvc

Comment: wait what mvc are you using? aspnetcore. mvc or asp.net mvc ?