# Dotnet core -> Best practice for web api content type when returning base64 string of jpg image

Tags: c#, .net-core, webapi

```
    [Route("image/{fileName}")]
    [Produces("text/plain or what???")]
    public string image(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] b = fromsomewhere();
        return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(b);
    }
```

1. What should i put in produces?
2. Should i include "data:image/png;base64," in the response or should this be set on the client instead?!

I also considered using

```
 public dynamic image(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] b = fromsomewhere();
        return new FileContentResult(b, "image/jpg");
    }
```

Which is an easier approach and working but im still interesting what content-type should be set to for base64string...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to to return an image with Web API Get method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177576/how-to-to-return-an-image-with-web-api-get-method)

Comment: @tvdias It does not answer which content type i should use for base64string