# How to download an image from specific row from database with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to fetch an image from the database and show it in my react-native app.where I did go wrong?

```
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string query = @"select image from mydb.courses where id=@id";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersAppCon");
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        mycon.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
        {
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            table.Load(myReader);
            var fs = new FileStream(myReader, FileMode.Open);
            return File(fs, "application/octet-stream");
            myReader.Close();
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` will prevent the `close()` from being called. To return an image look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177576/how-to-to-return-an-image-with-web-api-get-method/39177684

Comment: Hi @Ali Mahmoudi, What is the error message? Could you please share your react component?

Comment: Hi Greg and @Rena, I fixed it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed it.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
{
    string pathImage = "";
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string query = @"select image from mydb.courses where id=@id";
    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersAppCon");
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        mycon.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            pathImage = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }
    var path = @$"{pathImage}";
    var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return File(fs, "image/jpeg");
}
```