# FileExtensionContentTypeProvider in .NET 6+

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-6.0

I am upgrading an old `ASP.NET Core 2.2` app to `.NET 6`

I was able to upgrade every package, however there is one that I'm missing:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
```

This package seems to be unmaintained, in fact the last available version on NuGet is 2.2.0, which is marked as deprecated.

I checked my app's code and the only class I am using from this package is the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider` class, which I use to translate file extensions to the corrisponding MIME type.

My question is: can this class be found elsewhere in a non-deprecated and up-to-date package? And if not, is there an non-deprecated equivalent that provides the same functionality (file extension to MIME type translation)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.staticfiles.fileextensioncontenttypeprovider?view=aspnetcore-7.0) is part of the ASP.NET Core, no extra packages are required nowadays. Check out the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) docs. Approach to handling dependencies changed considerably during this migration and many `Microsoft.AspNetCore` packages are not published anymore and should not be directly referenced in the .csproj file, setting project SDK to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` is enough.

To use ASP.NET Core functionality in a class library or with different project SDK specify `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` in the .csproj - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279).

Comment: Thanks for the info, however the project I am using this in is a library project, not a web app... are there any issues using the `Web` sdk in a simple library?

Comment: @Master_T you need to add `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />` to the library project - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279).

Comment: Using the FrameworkReference works, thanks! (as I suspected using the Web sdk doesn't work in a library, the project needs to have a Main).

Comment: have u checkd this alternative bro @Master_T https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34131326/using-mimemapping-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @user123456: thanks, but that answer suggests using FileExtensionContentTypeProvider, which is exactly what I am doing already... maybe you didn't fully understand the question. At any rate, Guru's suggestion works, so no need for further suggestions. Thanks anyawy.

Comment: ok I will revise i thought it is fully alternative.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` package is also deprecated

Comment: @Saibamen package - maybe, the modern approach is to add `FrameworkReference` as written in the corresponding comment, and framework is far from being deprecated ATM.