# I need help to upgrade deprecated dependencies in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dependencies, .net-6.0, .net-8.0

I just upgraded an ASP.NET Core Web API project from .NET 6 to .NET 8. I would like to remove all the deprecated dependencies but I have some problems.

For example, when updating `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` from 3.1.0 to 5.2.0, I get the following error

> Error NU1605
> Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: System.Threading.Tasks from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
> BD.Shared.DWA -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.5 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime .win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Threading.Tasks (>= 4.3.0)
> BD.Shared.DWA -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core 2.2.5 -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel 2.1.0 -> Microsoft.DotNet.PlatformAbstractions 2.1.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> System .Threading.Tasks (>= 4.0.11) BD.Shared.DWA D:\GIT\DWA\MAIN\BD.Shared.DWA\BD.Shared.DWA.csproj 1

In fact the dependency `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core`, deprecated too, contains the dependency to `System.Threading.Tasks` v4.0.11

[image]

[image]

this the project file

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
  <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
  <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <ProduceReferenceAssembly>False</ProduceReferenceAssembly>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="HtmlAgilityPack" Version="1.11.36" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="7.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.15.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Threading.Tasks" Version="4.0.11" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DWA.Logging\DWA.Logging.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\DWA.Product.Configuration\DWA.Product.Configuration.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Update="BD.Shared.DWA.nlog">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="Config\BD.Shared.DWA.Production.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="Config\BD.Shared.DWA.Staging.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="Config\BD.Shared.DWA.Development.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  <None Update="Config\BD.Shared.DWA.Local.json">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there a way to upgrade `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to 5.0.2?

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` is deprecated but isn't a newer version, what can I replace it with?

Comment: Can you please share full csproj file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have explicitly installed `System.Threading.Tasks` - remove it.

Also remove all `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` packages, those are obsolete - see the [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references) guide:

> A large number of NuGet packages aren't produced for ASP.NET Core 3.0. Such package references should be removed from your project file.

Hence those packages are not distributed anymore and come with the framework/runtime itself.

See also:

1. [What Nuget packages must be referenced by an ASP.NET Core 6 application parts project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71320864/2501279)
2. [FileExtensionContentTypeProvider in .NET 6+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76235903/2501279)

Comment: hi, but removing that dependencies i got some compile errors, for example the class TypeFilterAttribute doesn't exists anymore, do i have to rewrite the code using other classes or i can add some library in the place of Microsoft.AspNetCore.* ?

Comment: @FDB It exists - see yourself in the "Applies to" section of [`TypeFilterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.typefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0)

Comment: @FDB Can't definitely claim that but based on the info present you might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71321740/2501279) useful.

Comment: adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.2.0 it compiles, now i need to check if there's some runtime, you were very helpful.

Comment: @FDB was glad to help! Still you should not add obsolete packages (and this is not needed). If you need ASP.NET Core stuff in class library add `FrameworkReference` as specified in the answer linked in the previous comment.